# In Pathfinder, what does it mean for a spell to have multiple versions?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spellcasting

In the rules for magic, I came across this interesting line:

> If a spell has multiple versions, you choose which version to use when you cast it. You don’t have to prepare (or learn, in the case of a bard or sorcerer) a specific version of the spell.

What exactly qualifies as a "version", and what does this mean for prepared casters? I assume 'greater', 'lesser', 'mass', and 'communal' variants of spells are separate versions, but how does this apply to learning, preparing, and casting spells?

I've always operated under the understanding that, for example, *Lesser Restoration* and *Restoration* were two separate spells that must be learned and prepared separately.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pathfinder took this sentence verbatim from the d20 System (under the OGL), which took it verbatim from *Dungeons & Dragons* v.3.5 revised edition (as the authors of the d20 System were also the copyright holders for D&D 3.5e).

However, the d20 System was pretty strictly limited to just the rules themselves—a lot of commentary, examples, illustrations, and so on were left out of the System Reference Document. Thus, the original context for this statement:

> If a spell has multiple versions, you choose which version to use when you cast it. You don’t have to prepare (or learn, in the case of a bard or sorcerer) a specific version of the spell. For example, *resist energy* protects a creature from fire, cold, or other energy types. You choose when you cast the spell which energy type it will protect the subject from.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook*, D&D 3.5e, 2004, pg. 170)</sup>

To my mind, however, *resist energy* isn’t the best example they could have chosen. To my mind, the best examples of spells with multiple versions are [*dispel magic*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/):

> You choose to use *dispel magic* in one of two ways: a targeted dispel or a counterspell.
>
> - *Targeted Dispel:* […]
> - *Counterspell:* […]

and *greater dispel magic*:

> You choose to use *greater dispel magic* in one of three ways: a targeted dispel, area dispel, or a counterspell:
>
> - *Targeted Dispel:* […]
> - *Area Dispel:* […]
> - *Counterspell:* […]

When you learn or prepare *dispel magic* or *greater magic*, you get both (all three) of these versions. You do not have prepare *targeted dispel magic* or learn *greater area dispel magic*, you just prepare *dispel magic* or learn *greater dispel magic*, and cast it as whichever version you want.

*Dispel magic* and *greater dispel magic* also illustrate a case where things are **not** simply “versions” of one spell: that is, *dispel magic* and *greater dispel magic* are not versions of one another. They are separate spells. Related spells, of course, but separate, which means you **do** have to prepare or learn them separately.

Likewise, your examples of *restoration* and *lesser restoration*, and other qualifiers, such as the “mass” or “communal,” are not versions; those are separate spells.

In short: if it is one spell entry, with one set of school, descriptors, level, and so on, just listed within the one spell description, those are versions of one spell. Those are what the quote refers to. If they are separate spell entries, with their own name, levels, and so on, then they are not, and you need to learn/prepare those separately.

Comment: I agree that this is how these spells function, but I don't know if I'm convinced that this is what the rule is referring to as 'versions'. Is there any other supporting rules text that can back up this answer?

Comment: @baphomet Fair enough: how’s it look now?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that there are a bunch of psychic spells that have an exception: learning one of the set also lets you cast all lower-level forms.

Comment: @KRyan great explanation. Good catch on the omitted example from 3.5. I figured it was probably something like that.

Comment: @sideromancer or the core D&D 3.5e spell Polymorph Any Object that can function as several other lower level spells of the caster so wishes.

Answer (score 4):

> I've always operated under the understanding that, for example, Lesser
> Restoration and Restoration were two separate spells that must be
> learned and prepared separately.

Your initial understanding is correct: *Lesser Restoration* and *Restoration* are entirely separate spells and not merely the same version of one another.

---

This line of the rules actually applies to a few spells where the caster can make specific choices about the spell. An example are the spells [Form of the Alien Dragon](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Form%20of%20the%20Alien%20Dragon%20I) and [Form of the Exotic Dragon](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Form%20of%20the%20Exotic%20Dragon%20I), where the caster chooses to become an "esoteric or outer dragon" / "imperial or primal dragon". These spells are good examples, because the spells contain text that specifically restricts Psychics / Druids to certain versions of the spell:

> **Form of the Alien Dragon:**
> You become a Medium esoteric or outer dragon. *Psychics can choose from
> the esoteric dragon (astral, dream, etheric, nightmare, or occult)
> forms only.*

> **Form of the Exotic Dragon:**
> You become a Medium imperial or primal dragon. *Druids can choose from
> the primal dragon (brine, cloud, crystal, magma, or umbral) forms
> only.*

All other casters can cast any version of the spell, i.e. they can freely choose which dragon to polymorph into.

There are also other spells like [Create Demiplane](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Create%20Demiplane), that have two versions of the spell:

> This spell functions as create lesser demiplane, except the area is
> larger and you can add more features to the plane. You can use this
> spell to expand a demiplane you created with create lesser demiplane
> (you do not need to create an entirely new plane using this spell), in
> which case it has a duration of 1 day/level. *Alternatively, when cast
> within your demiplane, you may add (or remove) one of the following
> features to your demiplane with each casting of the spell, in which
> case it has an instantaneous duration.*

or the famous "divine Wish" spell [Miracle](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Miracle):

> Alternatively, a cleric can make a very powerful request. Casting such
> a miracle costs the cleric 25,000 gp in powdered diamond because of
> the powerful divine energies involved. Examples of especially powerful
> miracles of this sort could include the following:

These "alternatively" sections indicate such other versions of using the spell.